# How to pass generic type deep down into the app?

Tags: typescript

How can I pass generic type deep down into my app? I'm building a middleware and I want it to be framework agnostic. I'm initializing my middleware with generic values, thus I expect it to pass it down to internal classes and methods, but it's not happening:

```
app.use(
  umbress<express.Request, express.Response>({
    ipAddressExtractor: (request) => request.headers['x-forwarded-for'],
    // -----------------^^^^^^^^^------------------------
    // request type here shoud be express.Request, instead it's R
  }),
);
```

`umbress` function is being initialized like this:

```
export default function umbress<R, S>(userOptions: UmbressOptions): (request: R, response: S) => void {
  const processor = new ProcessorService<R, S>(userOptions, optionsServiceInstance, ipBasedMitigationServiceInstance);
  //------------------------------------^^^^^^----------------------------------
  // passing down generic values here

  return processor.process;
}
```

Then `ProcessorService` also accepts generics:

```
export class ProcessorService<R, S> {
```

After that method `process` uses those generics for argument types:

```
async process(request: R, response: S): Promise<S | void> {
    const ipAddress = this.#options.ipAddressExtractor<R>(request);
```

And `ipAddressExtractor` is defined inside of object `type`  like this:

```
ipAddressExtractor<R>(request: R): string;
```

Have I missed something? And how can I fix it?

EDIT: Here's full reproducible example:

```
type UmbressOptions = {
  ipAddressExtractor<R>(request: R): string;
};

class ProcessorService<R, S> {
  #options: UmbressOptions;

  constructor(userOptions: UmbressOptions) {
    this.#options = userOptions;
  }

  async process(request: R): Promise<S | void> {
    const ipAddress = this.#options.ipAddressExtractor<R>(request);
  }
}

function umbress<R, S>(userOptions: UmbressOptions): (request: R, response: S) => void {
  const processor = new ProcessorService<R, S>(userOptions);
  // ------------------------------------^^^^^^----------------------------------
  // passing down generic values here

  return processor.process;
}

umbress<Request, Response>({
  ipAddressExtractor: (request) => request.headers['x-forwarded-for'],
  // -----------------^^^^^^^^^-----------^^^^^^^^--------------------
  // `request` implicitly has type `any` because R is not set to a default value
});
```

You may need to run `npm i defaults cache-manager` to enable full type resolution.

Comment: @jcalz updated my question. Please navitage to the repository mentioned and try pulling the code from specified branch. Let me know i I can assist in any way.

Comment: @jcalz done. I have included a minimal reproducible example at the end of my question.

Comment: @jcalz not necessarily. Express is one of the frameworks I intend to support. Basically you should be able to pass any interface you want instead of `express.Request` or `express.Response`. It's there only for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to make your `UmbressOptions` generic, e.g:

```
type UmbressOptions<Request> = CachingOptions & {
  ipAddressExtractor(request: Request): string;
};
```

So your `OptionsService` will also need to be generic, e.g.:

```
class OptionsService<Request> {
  mergeDefaultsAndUserProvidedOptions<T extends Record<string, unknown> = UmbressOptions<Request>>(
    defaults: T,
    userOptions: T,
  ): T {
    return combine<T, T>(defaults, userOptions);
  }
}
```

Your `umbress` function needs to be updated to pass the `R` type parameter into `UmbressOptions`, e.g.

```
function umbress<R, S>(userOptions: UmbressOptions<R>): (request: R, response: S) => void {
  const processor = new ProcessorService<R, S>(userOptions, optionsServiceInstance);
  //------------------------------------^^^^^^----------------------------------
  // passing down generic values here

  return processor.process;
}
```

Now when you call your `umbress` function, request is correctly inferred:

```
app.use(
  umbress<express.Request, express.Response>({
    ipAddressExtractor: (request) => request['x-forwarded-for'],
    // -----------------^^^^^^^^^-----------^^^^^^^^--------------------
    // request is now `express.Request`
  }),
);
```

Comment: Yep, that works. Thank you!